# How Can I Make A Voice For My AI Assistant

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

I am making an Ai assistant using python's Tensorflow module. Now I am trying to make a voice for my Ai assistant. Like Google assistant, Cortana, Siri all of them has their own voice. But I don't know how to make an artificial voice. I searched the web but not getting any helpful answer.

Can someone please tell me a way of making a artificial voice or just the methods I should look for. I don't know what this process is called. Probably that's why I can't find any answer on the web. It would be nice if someone please help me!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to add a voice to your AI assistant is to use a text-to-speech library like:

- [pyttsx3](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3)
- [gTTS](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS)
- Google's [text-to-speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/)

If you want to add your own voice, you could use deep learning for that, like in:

- [Real-Time-Voice-Cloning](https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning)
- more approaches in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-to-speech-lifelike-speech-synthesis-demo-part-1-f991ffe9e41e)